# Grep/egrep regex not working correctly?

Tags: command-line, grep

I seem to be using `grep` incorrectly. Observe:

```
>    hg log <filepath> | egrep changeset
changeset:   3961:9dedc55e030a
changeset:   3651:d23495ab1168
changeset:   2974:6aa71cb2c575
changeset:   2756:9dd7fb635678
changeset:   2532:d3ced9af4d6c
changeset:   2459:9d5f5553b851
changeset:   1835:4558836beed1
changeset:   1628:517d0239e830
```

But when I use a more particular regex, to try and go by number of digits in the changeset, it comes up blank.

```
>    hg log <filepath> | egrep \d{3,6}
>    egrep: d6: No such file or directory
```

Why might this be? If I just use `\d` on its own then it returns everything again.

Comment: See this similar question on U&L: [Using egrep in Bash](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195161/using-egrep-in-bash/195163#195163) - the issue is likely the same i.e. your shell is performing brace expansion on the unquoted `{3,6}`

Comment: Use `grep -P` instead. It uses even more extended regex: `cmd | grep -P "\d{3,6}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\d{3,6}` is being parsed by Bash as `d3 d6`. This means it's being passed to `egrep` as two arguments, which means it's trying to open the second one as a file, because that's grep's syntax.

```
grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]
```

The solution is simple. Stop Bash interfering and quote your regex:

```
... | egrep '\d{3,6}'
```

Comment: But why on earth is bash parsing it that way? (late reply, I know.)

Comment: Wow that was! Welcome back. Bash parses it because that's what bash does with unquoted stuff. [Brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) is a thing and it's really cool for writing curt commands.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea brace expansion was a thing-- and I've done a fair amount of bash scripting by now. But what about the backslash in front of the `d`?

Comment: Backslash is an escape character. The same is true as is for tother special characters. You either have to quote it, or escape it.